Discord.py how do I fetch related user info, if the function seemingly has no connection to it?
Trying to add a part to a bot, where certain users, due to easy abuse, can't create new roles. Using on_guild_role_create(role) works fine when removing the newly created roles, but it's inconsiderate, and will delete roles regardless of who made it, if the bot has the needed permission level.
From what I've seen in the API Reference, there's no linkage to the creator at all. Is there a way I can fetch the creator user id or anything related to them?

One solution I thought of so far, which seems to be working perfectly fine, is to fetch the audit log, check the latest role created entry, and match the maker id with the one I want to block.
This should work with any other action you'd want to detect, from any other event, that may not have linkage.
spammer = 111111111111#userid here

@bot.event
async def on_guild_role_create(role):
    async for entry in role.guild.audit_logs(action=discord.AuditLogAction.role_create, limit=1):
        if entry.target.id == role.id:
            if entry.user.id == spammer:
                await role.delete()

PS: ty for that one really helpful guy with the "no..........." answer, insightful
